# How do you specify include directory path in F#?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am using F# in Visual Studio 2012 and this may seem like a dumb question but I cannot figure out how to specify include directories, specifically for binaries. I see how to do it for F# interactive using the #I directive and it works there, but the #I option is not available in the non-interactive form. The compiler error message says to use the -I compiler option. I have looked under Project Properties, where the only subsections visible are Application, Build, Build Events, Debug, and Reference Paths none of which provides any obivous way to specify an include directory path. The help system isnt much help as it seems to reference sections that are unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

Well i still have the problem with VS12 but at least i have a workaround, by calling the compiler from the command line. You have to use the -r option to specify the location of the dll:
`fsc -r:<complete path to dll> <fname>`
However when i try the corresponding step in VS (by trying to set one of the Reference Paths) it says there are no items found in the DLL folder. So perhaps someone familiar with CS can help out